# Spring data jpa cannot find my custom implementation method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to provide a Custom Implementation of repository using Spring Data JPA. I have :

```
public interface PersonRepositoryCustom{

    List<Person> chercher(String name);

}
```

And the implementation :

```
 public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepositoryCustom{

        List<Person> chercher(String name){ 
// my implementation
         }

    }
```

The two classes are in the jpa:repositories package

Here is my Person DAO:

```
public interface IPersonDAO extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>,PersonRepositoryCustom{ 
// other methods here
}
```

When i launch the server i am getting the error :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property chercher found for type Person
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:291)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:271)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
```

Comment: You probably need to supply more code.  I'd guess you're missing the  EnableJparepositories annotation?  Or possibly you're missing the Repository annotation on the repository?

Comment: in the documentation here there is not mention of annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: It's find the repository and the method but spring try to guess which attributes to fetch using the method name of the interface. I think Spring does not see the implementation.

Comment: PersonRepositoryImpl should be a class, not an interface.

Comment: Which version of spring-data-jpa are you using?

Comment: @Ricardo Veguilla the version on spring-data-jpa is 1.5

Comment: @user2824691 I don't need the findByName.

Answer (score 9):

I've found the answer. Spring-data-jpa use a convention to write CustomRepository. To achieve this task : we have to have as explained in the [Spring Data JPA documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) . We have to create a interface in which we add custom method :

```
public interface PersonRepositoryCustom{

    List<Person> chercher(String name);

}
```

Suppose we have following DAOService :

```
public interface IPersonDAO extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>,PersonRepositoryCustom{ 
// other methods here
}
```

So the implementation of custom repository is :**IPersonDAOImpl**

```
public class IPersonDAOImpl implements PersonRepositoryCustom{

        List<Person> chercher(String name){ 
// my implementation
         }

    }
```

And not **PersonRepositoryImpl**

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think they should outline that the implementation as to use the name of the repository itself and not the custom interface.

Comment: thanks for pointing to specific part of documentation - what helped me with my problem (having custom repository to be shared among multiple repositories)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me :(.

Comment: Oh man, it also has to be in the same namespace! dumb...